# angularjs allow dom event propagation/bubbling

Tags: angularjs

I prefer to add event listener to a parent, use propagation/bubbling effect to identify which child is say clicked then do something. While I can implement this in ES6, I just can't do it with AngularJS.
Consider the example below. How can I make this work?

```
<section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ol ng-click="addColor($event)">
        <li class="item" ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}</li>
    </ol>
</section>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = ["Tea", "Coffee", "Chocolate", "Akamu", "Ogi"];
    $scope.addColor = function($event) {
        if ($event.target.classList.contains('item')) {
            //do something

        }
   }
});
```

Comment: Please specify what do you want to do in this case. Because you can just put your ng-click on the <li> and identify which item in the loop was clicked

Comment: Remove element clicked

Comment: One concern is that ES6 discourages adding eventlistener to each <li> Hence the eventlisterner will be on <ul>